# как сделать симуляцию дискретной жидкости в 3d пространстве

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, физика

Нужно сделать симуляцию жидкости в поле тяжести для LED кубика. Есть акселерометр, с него получаю всякие ускорения, направления и проч. Кубик 8*8*8, хотелось бы, чтобы расчеты шли на ардуинке, но могу и распбери подключить. Может кто-нибудь подсказать, куда вообще смотреть, в сторону каких библиотек или статей или..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Закон Ньютона.

`F = ma`

Сила, действующая на частицу, придаёт частице ускорение. Частица двигается, пока не сталкивается с другой частицей.

В данном случае кубик 8x8x8. Пусть он заполнен наполовину. Размер частицы будет 0.5x0.5x0.5 пикселей.

Таким образом, имеется 8x16x16 = 2048 частиц. Их движение эмулирует программа, а кубик используется в качестве дисплея для отображения текущего кадра.

Определяете максимальную частоту кадров, получаете временной интервал `Δt` для расчёта движения частиц.